# How to execute last line of CMD execution regardless of how second to last returned

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe

I've got a simple batch file that executes a script and never runs the final line.  That is, in the example below, I'm executing the "dir" command and after that returning to the directory I started in.

When I replace the "dir" command with my own program, the last line does not get executed. I assume there must be a return code or something else causing that.

My question is how can I always get the last line to execute (the cd current) regardless of what happened on the line before that.

```
set current="%cd%"
cd %1
dir
cd "%current%"
```

Comment: Is your "program" another batch file?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure the type. I installed it from nodejs ad it executes from the command line.  any what to tell what it is?

Comment: If it is in the path, you can use `where theprogramname` to find it. If it has `bat` or `cmd` extension, it is a batch file. If it is a batch file you need to use `call theprogramname` from inside a batch file so the execution returns to the caller.

Comment: where tells me it is a cmd file